# Add Spinner in recyclerview header and manage it's selection from It's fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am having a `fragment` in which I have `recyclerview` inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Now I want to add a header to `recyclerview` that contains a `spinner` which I am able to do from RecyclerView Adapter, now the issue is I want to apply `setOnItemSelectedListener` on this spinner and perform some action on it, but I want this to process from the `fragment` class not from the adapter, but I am not able to do this.

Can you please guide me, how can I achieve this.

Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method in the Adapter class e.g.:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    // From my understanding you created the Spinner from within the Adapter.
    // So it would live here.
    public Spinner mySpinner;

    @Override
    public CustomFieldViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create ViewHolder.
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // Return the number of itemViews in the RecyclerView here!
        // Usually the size of the dataset being mapped to "rows" (itemViews).
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Map the current item in the dataset to a particular view.
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // Called when the ViewHolder is created / recycled.
    }

    public int getSpinnerSelection() {
         // Just an example. You would have your custom method here.
        return mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }
}
```

You can simply call the public method from your Fragment class where you will have an instance of you recycler's Adapter. Like so:

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    // ... Fragment methods.

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        RecyclerView myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_recycler);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new new MyAdapter(/* things here for initialiser */);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Button myButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Use the reference to the adapter to call your custom method.
                int numItemsInRecyclerView = myAdapter.getSpinnerSelection();
                myTextView.setText("Number of items : " + numItemsInRecyclerView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```